# Reverse lookup of ArrayList of Array values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In my quest to continue my java education I'm trying to figure out if there is a native java method that quickly and efficiently allows a lookup of a string value in a ArrayList of Arrays.

Here is my code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
 public void exampleArrayListofArray () {
        ArrayList<String []> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(new String[] {"AB","YZ"});
        al.add(new String[] {"CD","WX"});
        al.add(new String[] {"EF","UV"});
        al.add(new String[] {"GH","ST"});
        al.add(new String[] {"IJ","QR"});
        al.add(new String[] {"KL","OP"});
        displayArrayListofArray(al);
    }

    public void displayArrayListofArray(List<String []> al) {

        for (String [] row : al)
            for (int column = 0; column <= 1 ; column ++){
                System.out.println("Value at Index Row " + al.indexOf(row) +
                        " Column " + column + " is " + (row)[column]);
            }

        String lookUpString = "YZ";
        lookUpMethod(al, lookUpString);
        lookUpString = "ST";
        lookUpMethod(al, lookUpString);
        lookUpString = "IJ";
        lookUpMethod(al, lookUpString);
        lookUpString = "AA";
        lookUpMethod(al, lookUpString);
    }

    public void lookUpMethod(List<String []> al, String lookUpString) {
        boolean isStringFound = false;
        for (String[] row : al) {
            for (int column = 0; column <= 1; column++) {
                if (al.get(al.indexOf(row))[column] == lookUpString) {
                    System.out.println("Index of '" + lookUpString + "': " + al.indexOf(row) + column);
                    isStringFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isStringFound) {
            System.out.println("Search string '" + lookUpString + "' does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

Is this the most efficient way of searching my ArrayList for a given string?
Is there anything that I should be doing to make my code more efficient (besides not using an ArrayList)?

I know that perhaps to do what I'm trying to do here there could be more efficient ways of doing it than an ArrayList such as a HashMap but with my currently very limited java knowledge I'm making progress with ArrayList and would have to start from scratch using a HashMap.  The very end goal of my code is to do the following:

1. Read an asset text file to load the ArrayList
2. Search the ArrayList for a user entered value
3. Do some calcs with the neighbouring values in the searched row
4. Allow the user to update the neighbouring values at the searched row
5. Allow the user to add a new row if the searched string is not found
6. Save any changes back to the asset text file in alphabetical order

Airfix

Comment: There are native ways to lookup elements of any given `Collection`, but in this case you are looking inside every array in that given collection, so there's no native way. For a more streamlined, concise and "declarative" algorithm, I would advise using Java 8 lambdas.

Comment: If you have sorted the collections before, you could apply binary search, which would run in O(log n) instead of O(n). Also, you can return from the search method if you found one match instead of running through all other remaining lists and arrays.

Comment: Also I might have found a bug: If you check strings for equality, you must use the `firstString.equals(secondString)`-Method. The `==`-Operator only returns true, if both String references point to the exact same location in memory.

Comment: @Palle Thanks for the bug find.  For a given string in what scenario would both strings point to a different location in memory?  As it currently stands both strings must be in the same spot in memory because I get the results I expect.  However I'll do some more research and change the code accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Airfix The only time a string and another string point to the same location in memory is if the second string is assigned from the first string: `String a = "something;"` and `String b = a;` Only in this case, `a==b` returns true. If for example the user inputs a string `a` (through a textfield or the command line) and you want to check given possibilities, even if the entered string contains the same value as the string you compare with `b`, `a==b` will return false.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. Normally I would show my gratitude directly - but (no kidding) I ran out of votes today. So, if you dont mind to be upvoted, drop me a comment tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is: don't worry.

I think you are looking at this from the wrong angle: if you find that the users of your application have a "performance" issue; and if you then do profiling, and then profiling shows that your current "search" code is the "culprit" (the single hot-spot that kills "end user perceived performance"); then you will have to bite the bullet and learn about using different data structures than ArrayLists. 
(side note there: in reality, Set/HashSet isn't much "different"; learning how to use them ... isn't as big of a deal as it might sound).

But: if you answered any of the above "questions" with "no" (like: you do not have users that complain about bad performance) ... then there is no point in worrying about performance.

Long story short: either performance is really an issue - then you have to solve it. Otherwise: don't try to fix something that is not broken.

(as said: from a learning perspective, I would still encourage you to save your code; and start a new version that uses sets. There are plenty of tutorials out there that explain all the things you need to know).

But just to give you some direction: your main "performance" killer is (as you thought yourself) the inappropriate usage of data structures. There is no advantage in using an ArrayList to store arrays of strings that you want to search for. That adds "two layers"; each one requiring your code to iterate those "lists" in an sequential way. If you would use a single Set (like HashSet) instead; and add all your "search strings" to that set, your whole "lookup" for matches ... boils down to ask that set: "do you contain this value".

Comment: "In my quest to continue my java education" I think he is worrying about it now, so he doesn't have to in the future if said problem occurs

Comment: I don't think there will be any perceived performance hit from my users (initially only me).  The end ArrayList will only be 100 to 150 lines long.  However I'm trying to get a workable solution with minimal time investment right now.  Then once it's working, through the revision process, I want to go and tighten everything up as my java knowledge grows. I'm thinking about it now so I know what to study for future improvements. Can you point me in the direction of a worthy hashset tutorial?

Comment: @Airfix Side note: "perceived performance" comes from two ends: first the efficiency of your computations; then from the size of your data. So maybe 150 search patterns; but how many lines in your files. If you are talking about < 100000 ... probably still no big deal. But if your files are **large** ... you will learn quickly the difference between the O ( n * n ) and O ( 1 ). (search for big o notation to understand what I mean there)